# searching through a list for a number

Tags: python

i have a list with the data split into strings, the list looks like this

```
['Equifax', 'BUY', 'Icelandic', 'Krona:', '41983']
```

i want to split it up so that each value has a different variable so i used the following code

```
    yourlist = line.split()
    company=yourlist[0]
    action=yourlist[1]
```

my problem is i need to set currency equal to everything after action and before the final value in the list so icelandic and krona would be the currency. so how do i set ammount to the final element of the list and then curreny equal to everything in between action and ammount?

Comment: Use list slicing -  http://www.dotnetperls.com/slice

Answer (score 2):

You'll need list [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
l = ['Equifax', 'BUY', 'Icelandic', 'Krona:', '41983'] 
# l is a list, no need for split()

company = l[0]

action = l[1]

currency = l[2:-1]
# the previous lines sliced the list starting at the 3rd element
# stopping, but not including, at the last item

amount=l[-1]
# counting backwards [-1] indicates last item in a list.

company
Out[22]: 'Equifax'

action
Out[23]: 'BUY'

currency
Out[24]: ['Icelandic', 'Krona:']

amount
Out[25]: '41983'
```

Comment: `currency = l[2:-1]`.